# How to test sms containing different language words

Tags: manual-testing, mobile

I want to test content of the sms. The content would be in different languages like dutch, german, latin. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? Are you trying to test that characters such as ö dont cause errors? Or is the content translated?

Comment: As for now only the characters. Some words will have characters in languages like dutch, german etc...

Comment: So how would you test these characters if it wasn't SMS? Don't the same test principles apply?

Comment: In Web application, i copy pasted the word in find option to check for all the matches on a particular page. Is there a way i can do the same in sms content

Answer (score 1):

Start by learning something about SMS encoding [for example from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Message_size)

Then try to understand how phones decode and encode SMSs

I think you'll have a clearer idea of how and what to test.